# Change the URL of an image from wp_get_attachment_image_src for Product Posts based on Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the URL of an image from `wp_get_attachment_image_src` for Product `Posts` based on their `Category`, for example:

If a product post is in product category 1, this will be it's image source '`http://newimagesrc.com/myimage_category_1.jpg`' and if it is in product category 2 this will be it's image source '`http://newimagesrc.com/myimage_category_2.jpg`' and so on for 10 categories...

Below is a working code but it has no feature that I needed to assign different image per category:

```
function alterImageSRC($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon){        
$image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage.jpg';

return $image;
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work:

```php
function alterImageSRC( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ) {

    // Get the product/post object for the current page
    global post;

    // Set a variable for the two categories
    $cat_1 = 'category_1';
    $cat_2 = 'category_2';

    // Get the array list of all the categories associated with the particular product
    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    // Assign all the product categories to a $categories variable
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ){ $categories[] = $cat->slug};

    // Check for your specific categories and assign the product image
    if ( in_array( $cat_1, $categories ) ) :
        $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage' . $cat_1 . 'jpg';
    else:
        $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage' . $cat_2 . 'jpg';
    endif;

    return $image;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

but you can also use this:

```php
function alterImageSRC( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ) {

    // Set a variable for the two categories
    $cat_1 = 'category_1';
    $cat_2 = 'category_2';

    // Check for the category
    if ( has_term( $cat_1, 'product_cat' ) ) :
        $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage' . $cat_1 . 'jpg';
    else:
        $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage' . $cat_2 . 'jpg';
    endif;

    return $image;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

i hope one of this works ..

Comment: Thank you for bro, but how do I do it for 10 categories?

Comment: @BlogMarkz ... Assume you know the categories then use switch statement to check for each category ...